# timeout error message when running sudo visudo

Tags: macos, terminal, visudo

I was trying to install yabai on my Big Sur mac, and ran into an issue when trying to do visudo. After some playing around, I found that I was running into issues even with just `sudo visudo` (i.e., the problem isn't with yabai):

```
❯ sudo visudo
Timeout waiting for detached instance to start: No such file or directory
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
```

Nor does adding an editor flag work:

```
❯ sudo EDITOR="vim" visudo
Timeout waiting for detached instance to start: No such file or directory
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged

❯ sudo EDITOR="nano" visudo
Timeout waiting for detached instance to start: No such file or directory
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
```

I'm using zsh.

Would any of you happen to know how to get around this?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `visudo` is trying to run Sublime Text despite your use of an `EDITOR` environment variable. I suspect that this is because you have it set in the `SUDO_EDITOR` or `VISUAL` environment variables, both of which take precedence over `EDITOR` if they're set. Try `sudo SUDO_EDITOR="vim" visudo` or `sudo SUDO_EDITOR="nano" visudo` instead.

If that isn't it, the other possibility is that in your `sudoers` file, `env_editor` is disabled and so `editor` is forcing the use of Sublime Text.

Comment: Thanks so much, this was exactly the right diagnosis! I did indeed have sublime set in my VISUAL variable.

Comment: @qwyh If my answer solved your problem, please accept it with the check mark.

Comment: Done! Sorry for not realizing I should have done that.